# Using "helper" method in view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I made a helper in my rails project that makes a request in an external api and get a certain value from it.

```
    def show_CoinPrice coin
        begin
            coinTicker = JSON.parse(HTTParty.get("https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/#{coin}/ticker/").body)
            "R$ #{coinTicker["ticker"]["last"].to_number.round}"
        rescue
            "---"
        end
    end
```

However I have doubts if this was a good practice to do (this code caused slowness in my view), there is something I can do better, whether with a controller or something ?!

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly makes the code slow? How often do you call it per view? Do you cache or store the values you loaded somewhere, for example in your database? Or do you load the data from the external resource again when you reload the page?

Comment: You could load the data client-side via JavaScript.

Comment: @spickermann. Exactly, it's load the data from the external resource again when you reload the page

Answer (score 1):

I think u should request to external API using client-side (JS). Cs fetching API with rails helper it's will run while your server is rendering view.